# Relationship between univariate normal distribution and multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, vectors

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3$ is column vector and $H = [a_1 a_2 a_3]$.
If $a_i$ have standard normal distribution, is this following statement true ?
$$ vec(H) = [(a_1)^T (a_2)^T (a_3)^T]^T$$ have multivariate normal distribution, where $T$ denote transpose.
I think the statement is true but I just guessing.

Comment: Are there any independence assumptions?

Comment: yes, but I forget to include that assumption in the question

Comment: In that case, yes, one has multivariate normal.

Comment: Where I can find the reason ?

Comment: Ordered $n$-tuples of independent normals are multivariate normal (but multivariate normal is a far more extensive clas.)   Wikiprdia has a reasonably good discussion.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $\mathrm{vec}(H)$ will have the joint distribution of $9$ i.i.d. standard normal distribtuions. This is [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) the same as a standard multivariate distribution of dimension $9$ (with covariance matrix $I_9$ and expected value $0\in\mathbb R^9$). So the answer is yes.